# Issue in graphic of Android Studio, it's working but it's not perfect

Tags: android-studio

Who knows how do I solve the issue in this picture? the text is hiding :( !

click here to see the pic > [Android Studio Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4piv.jpg) < click here to see the pic

I've cleaned the Hard-disk, RAM is OK, Processor isn't busy.. :\ so how can I show all the text

and the problem is in everything in The android Studio on my machine, not only in this picture

Answer (score 0):

There should be a check box you can check to stop it auto formatting and you can put in anything you like. I'll upload a picture soon.

Comment: That's reallllyyy weird how part of your text box is missing.. It seems like a graphics card issue. Are you sure it's only effecting Android Studio?